# Prevent loading of resources in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In every page of my app I have a "How to"-button which is opening an modal js view with a video/pictures which explains the current page.

The problem I am having is that this video/pictures is getting loaded on page load.
I only want to load this resources when "How to"-button is pressed.

How would I go about this?

PS. Images/videos is served with amazon S3.

Thanks.

Comment: That is a great idea, post it as an answer so I can accept it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove the video/pictures from the page and put it in its own view. When you click on the howto button, open a empty popup and make a ajax request to fetch the howto pictures/videos from the controller. Then append the answer to the ajax request (the pictures and videos) into the javascript popup. This way the pictures only get loaded when you press the howto button. I would recommend to make a new "howto" controller.